# Algorithm to portion

Tags: php, algorithm

I have a number X, consider `X = 1000`
And I want piecemeal this number at three times, then `Y = 3`, then `X = (X / 3)`
This will give me equal, just not always accurate, so I need: a percentage value is set, also consider `K = 8`, **K** is the percentage, but what I want to do? I want the first portion has a value over 8% in K, suppose that 8% are: **500** and the other two plots are **250**, **250**

The algorithm is basically what I need it, add a percentage value for the first installment and the other equals

Comment: I'm confused; in what way is `500` only 8% greater than `250`? I suggest giving more inputs and expected outputs. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: `I want the first portion has a value over 8% in K, suppose that 8% are: 500 and the other two plots are 250, 250` does not make any sense. How are these 8% related to your example?

Comment: guess, what I meant is that the value of the first installment should always be higher, but I want this 'bigger' is defined as a percentage, eg 3% in 1000, will give 30, then the first portion has that be your value + 30 and the other with the values ​​equal, the result: first installment 360, and to the other two 320

Comment: 3% of total value added were the first installment, the sum of other fields of the first modified to be equal to the aggregate

Comment: So, given X, Y, and K, split it into Y pieces { Y0 ... YN } where Y0 is K% greater than Y1 ... YN?

Comment: The 3% example doesn't (to me) make any sense.  `(int)1000/3` is 333 and 360 is not 3% higher.

Comment: Because it decrease in others parcels to equals in final.

Comment: Ah, so it needs to be 3% higher than the other values.  Got it.

Comment: For your first example, 1000 with 8%, would't the answer be (352, 324, 324)?  324 * 1.08 = 349.92.  324 * 2 + 352 = 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

I just realized, this is far simpler than I made it.  To find the value of `$div` in my original answer you can just:

```
$div = (int)($num / ($parcels + $percent / 100));
```

Then the `$final_parcels` will be the same as below.  Basically, the line above replaces the while loop entirely.  Don't know what I was thinking.

**/EDIT**

I think this will do what you want... unless I am missing something.

```
<?php

$num = 1000;
$percent = 8;
$parcels = 3;

$total = PHP_INT_MAX;
$div = (int)($num / $parcels);
while ($total > $num) {
  $div -= 1;
  $total = (int)($div * ($parcels + $percent / 100));
}

$final_parcels = array();
$final_parcels[] = ($num - (($parcels - 1) * $div));
for ($i = 1; $i < $parcels; $i++) {
  $final_parcels[] = $div;
}

print_r($final_parcels);
```

This output will be

```
Array
(
    [0] => 352
    [1] => 324
    [2] => 324
)

324 * 1.08 = 350. 
352 + 324 * 2 = 1000.
```

Answer (score 1):

Extra for the first piece  W = X*K/100

Remaining Z = X-W

Each non-first piece =  Z/Y = (X-W)/Y = (100-K)*X/(100*Y)

The first piece = W + (100-K)*X/(100*Y) = X*K/100 + (100-K)*X/(100*Y)

Comment: How does this work with OP's example (X=1000, Y=3; K=8)? It doesn't produce 500, 250, 250

Comment: `It doesn't produce 500, 250, 250` for K = 8 you can not get 500, 250, 250 at all. For K = 8 those numbers should be (rounded to ten) 330 + 80 = 410, 285 and 285

Comment: @TedHopp as Cheery mentioned I don't know how he got those numbers!

Answer (score 1):

Let `$T` is your total `X`, `$n` is a number of parts and `$K` is percentage mentioned above. Than

```
$x1 = $T / $n + $T * $K / 100;
$x2 = $x3 = .. = $xn = ($T - $x1) / ($n - 1);
```

Applied to your example:

```
$x1 = 1000 / 3 + 1000 * 0.03 = 363.3333333333333333333333333333 
// you could round it if you want
// lets round it to ten, as you mentioned
$x1 = round($x1, -1) = 360
$x2 = $x3 = (1000 - 360) / 2 = 320
```